# Regex repeated pattern

Tags: javascript, regex, ruby, regex-group

I am tryting the match the following pattern:

```
((1.0 4) (2.0 5) .... (10.0 8))
```

The tuple `(X N)`, where `X` is a floating point number with optional exponent and N is an integer, can be repeated several times.

I tried on [this](https://regex-generator.olafneumann.org/) website and I could generate a regex for a fixed number of tuples. For example for 2 tuples I would get

```
^\(\(([+-]?(?=\.\d|\d)(?:\d+)?(?:\.?\d*))(?:[eE]([+-]?\d+))?\s[0-9]+\)\s\(([+-]?(?=\.\d|\d)(?:\d+)?(?:\.?\d*))(?:[eE]([+-]?\d+))?\s[0-9]+\)\)$
```

How can I modify the pattern so that the number of tuples is arbitrary? I think I will have to use some kind of grouping, but regex is quite new for me.

Comment: You question needs greater specificity. At first (based largely on your example) I assumed that `X` is the string representation of a non-negative float with one digit to the right of the decimal point and `N` was the optional exponent. Now that I look at the regex you give I see neither of those assumptions were correct. At minimum you need to expand your example to include negative floats, exponents and so on. Also, make it a valid Javascript object (in part, no '....') so that readers can test code against your example and variants therefore, including invalid strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use the following pattern:

```regex
^\(\(\d+(?:\.\d+)? \d+\)(?:\s*\(\d+(?:\.\d+)? \d+\))*\)$
```

### Demo

This pattern matches:

```
^
\(                             (
\(\d+(?:\.\d+)? \d+\)          a leading tuple
(?:\s*\(\d+(?:\.\d+)? \d+\))*  space, more tuples
\)                             )
$
```

Comment: Wow, that was fast! Almost there. The second number must bit an integer. Your regex also matches `((1.0 2) (2.0 4) (3.0 8.0))`

Comment: It wasn't clear that the second number in the tuple were always an integer.  I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

> "The tuple (X N), where **X** is a *floating point number with optional exponent* and **N** is an *integer*, can be repeated several times."

To make sure you have 1+ tuples (with optional exponents), you can use:

```
^\(\([-+]?\d*\.\d+([eE][-+]?\d+)?\s\d+\)(?:\s\([-+]?\d*\.\d+([eE][-+]?\d+)?\s\d+\))*\)$
```

See an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/8CGR4a/1)

---

- `^` - Start-line anchor;
- `\(\(` - Two literal opening paranthesis;
- `[-+]?\d*\.\d+([eE][-+]?\d+)?` - To match your *floating point number with optional exponent* we match: An optional hypen or plus sign followed by 0+ digits and a literal dot with 1+ digits. After that is an optional capture group to match the exponent with a letter 'e', an optional hyphen or plus and 1+ digits;
- `\s\d+\)` - To finish the tuple the pattern matches: A single whitespace character and 1+ digits to match the *integer* part of the tuple before a closing paranthesis;
- `(?:\s.....)*` - The trick in the following is that we use a non-capture group to match a single whitespace char and the pattern we used for our tuple. When closing this non-capture group match it 0+ times to allow for any number of tuples;
- `\)$` - Finish the pattern with a literal closing paranthesis and the end-line anchor.

---

Or if available, catch the 1st tuple in a capture group and repeat that exact pattern with a backreference:

```
^\((\([-+]?\d*\.\d+([eE][-+]?\d+)?\h\d+\))(?:\h(?1))*\)$
```

See an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/AcRXxg/1)

Answer (score 1):

You can verify the pattern by matching the string with the following regular expression.

```
^\((?:\(\d+\.\d(?: \d+)?\)(?: |(?=\)$)))+\)$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/8wHJ77/1)

The regular expression can be broken down as follows.

```
^            # match beginning of string
\(           # match '('
(?:          # begin non-capture group
  \(         # match '('
  \d+\.\d    # match 1+ digits, '.', 1 digit
  (?: \d+)?  # optionally ('?') match a space then 1+ digits 
  \(         # match ')'
  (?:        # begin non-capture group
    [ ]      # match a space
    |        # or
    (?=\)$)  # positive lookahead asserts next char is ')' at end of string
  )          # end non-capture group
)+           # end non-capture group and execute one or more times
\)           # match ')'
$            # match end of string
```